# OpenCV rectangles not clearing after updating an image

Tags: c++, opencv, yolov5

I'm working with YoloV5 using object detection with OpenCv, my problem is that after I draw the bounding boxes of the detected objects they don't clear after the image source gets updated.
Here is the relevant code with the issue:

```cpp
    while (true) {
        //Loading Image

        cv::Mat target = getMat(hWND);
        
        cv::Mat frame;
        
        cv::cvtColor(target, target, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR);
        cv::cvtColor(target, target, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
        
        target.copyTo(frame);

        //Fps Counter
        frames++; //increments frames
        time(&current_time); //sets current_time
        
        //Object detection
        detect(frame, net, output, class_list);

        int detections = output.size();

        //Drawing boxes and text
        for (int i = 0; i < detections; ++i) {

            auto detection = output[i];
            auto box = detection.box;
            auto classId = detection.class_id;
            const auto color = colors[classId % colors.size()];
            cv::rectangle(frame, box, color, 3);

            cv::rectangle(frame, cv::Point(box.x, box.y - 20), cv::Point(box.x + box.width, box.y), color, cv::FILLED);
            cv::putText(frame, class_list[classId].c_str(), cv::Point(box.x, box.y - 5), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
        }

        cv::imshow("output", frame);
        cv::waitKey(30);

        //Fps counter continuation
        if (difftime(current_time, begin_time) >= 1.0) //if one second has passed since the loop started
        {
            printf("Frames: %.21f\n", frames); //print the frames run through in one second
            frames = 0; //reset frames
            time(&begin_time); //resets begin_time
        }

        //Break loop with key press
        if (_kbhit()) {
            key = _getch();
            if (key == KEY_W) {
                std::cout << "closing..." << std::endl;
                cv::destroyAllWindows();
                break;
            }

        }

    }
```

[image]
[image]
[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)

I'm not really sure how to fix this, been working a lot of hours today, so I'm pretty burnt out at the moment, so any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you need a deep copy of the frame. Use the .clone() method of  the cv::Mat type before drawing the rectangle, each time you update the rectangle.

Comment: I think I get what you are saying, but I'm not sure in which part of the code I should add that method. Could you be a little bit more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I just had to "empty" the output vector, it was accumulating all of the detections and drawing them every time at the for loop!

Answer (score 1):

You need a deep copy of the image. In OpenCV, all matrix assignments are shallow copies, i.e., the matrix data is shared amongst all assigned variables. If you re-use the same variables through your program, all further modifications to the data will persist every time you modify a variable that shares the same data.

You need a "fresh" copy of the frame for every time you draw new info to it. That will ensure you only modify data in one specific point of the program, by one specific variable. Further, as you modify a matrix with its own contents, the modifications wont persist each time you modify its info.

In OpenCV, you create a deep copy via the [.clone()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a03d2a2570d06dcae378f788725789aa4) method from the `cv::Mat` class. Before drawing the first rectangle, inside the `for` loop, create a deep copy. Then, write all your info to this image. Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < detections; ++i) {

    // Create a local, deep copy of frame:
    cv::Mat localMat = frame.clone();

    auto detection = output[i];
    auto box = detection.box;
    auto classId = detection.class_id;
    const auto color = colors[classId % colors.size()];

    // Modify the local deep copy here:
    cv::rectangle(localMat, box, color, 3);
    // here...
    cv::rectangle(localMat, cv::Point(box.x, box.y - 20), cv::Point(box.x + box.width, box.y), color, cv::FILLED);
    // and here:
    cv::putText(localMat, class_list[classId].c_str(), cv::Point(box.x, box.y - 5), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));

}
```

If you still see that information persists even after creating the deep copy, you are *shallow-modifying* `frame` elsewhere in the program (prior to deep-copying it). Be careful!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll implement those changes in a few hours and give an update.